# Big-list of classical facts

Tags: discussion, big-list

When we type an answer, we need sometimes classical facts, which will be long to expand and are well-known.

For example, a bounded measurable function can be approached uniformly by simple functions, or the fact that convergence in $L^p$ implies convergence almost everywhere of a sub-sequence.

I suggest to write in the answers a collection of these facts by fields (like "measure-theory", "real-analysis", etc...) including the fact and a link on the site to a question which deals with it. Since these fields are far from being disjoint, a same fact could belong to several answers.

The point is that if someone is looking for a proof of a fact, he/she will include a link in his/her answer after having found it in this page.

Comment: I think it should be CW, but I don't see how to do it.

Comment: I don't think this should be on the meta site; and I also don't really think that we need this. One can cite "classical facts" and if anyone wants to know more about these facts, one can ask a separate question and receive an answer (or ask in the comments, in some cases).

Comment: Most are also on wikipedia, which can be linked to of course!

Comment: while I think this is an intersting idea, I think it'd be quite hard to make it work in reality

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[PlanetMath](http://planetmath.org) and [ProofWiki](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Main_Page) are world-editable websites dedicated to collecting standard mathematical proofs. It might make more sense to post such results there, and then link to the proofs from particular questions here.

Comment: I agree. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @Will WTF?!?${}{}$

Comment: @WillJagy I'm not getting the joke.

Comment: David, it was a winner of the Diagram Prize for oddest book title of the year, for 2003. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookseller/Diagram_Prize_for_Oddest_Title_of_the_Year  It fit the Big List feeling of the question, and my wording was a suggestion that here was another resource we already had. I've deleted the direct link.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker, joke comment deleted and, to the extent possible, explained above. Apologies for any discomfort I may have caused.